# TIMESTAMP for function NOW() is updating when I open the Google Sheet to check the file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I have an Excel file that is distributed to the company's retail stores and their purpose is to check the completion of some tasks and for the managers to be able to track the time when the tasks were completed.
For convenience and time saving by employees there is a list of options for the status of work.
The list of options is in column D and in column E the formula,
[image]

which I copied from this website, is:

```
=IF(D4<>"";IF(E4<>"";E4;NOW());"")
```

The problem I'm having is when I open the files to check them the time changes to the time I opened them.

I also tried another script I copied from some answer on a similar topic:

```
function TIMESTAMP() {
    var today = new Date();
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    var date = today.getDate()+'/'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'/'+today.getFullYear();
    var dateTime = time+'-'+date;
    var timestamp_format = "dd-MM";
    return dateTime;
}
```

Using it in the formula:

```
=IF(D4<>"";TIMESTAMP();"")
```

but unfortunately, that didn't work either!

Is there a way someone can help me fix the formula or write a script that I can use inside column E that doesn't change the time and date?

Comment: `unfortunately, that didn't work either!` What do you mean? Does it update automatically?

Comment: I mean that when I open the spreadsheet again it updates the time and I cannot see the original time when the task was completed. It returns the time I opened it!

Comment: From [Google's Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092981?hl=en), `NOW will always represent the current date and time the last time the spreadsheet was recalculated, rather than remaining at the date and time when it was first entered.`

Comment: AFAICT, `=IF(D4<>"";TIMESTAMP();"")` should be static. Are you sure this causes the same issue?

Comment: @dek Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand the issue of my answer. And, I guess that your actual question is different from your showing question. My answer is for your showing question. In this case, I think that my answer was not useful for the actual question in your reply. So, I have to delete my answer. I apologize that I couldn't notice your actual question.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your reply! Your script works fine. Maybe my English are not good enough not yours. The question I added to you is how your script on the line const sheetName = "name of your sheet"; it can work regardless of the name of the sheet because each day has a different name depending on the day of the month that has the format DD/MM (eg 20/10, 21/10 etc.)

Comment: @dek It's better to ask follow up questions in a new post, so that the existing answers aren't invalidated or need editing. However, try `const sheetName=new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB',{day:'2-digit',month:'2-digit'}).format(new Date())`

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your reply. I will do what you suggested. I tried your script: "const sheetName=new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB',{day:'2-digit',month:'2-digit'}).format(new Date())" and it works for the first date 20/10 just fine like Tanaike but it is not working for the second date 21/10.

Comment: @dek Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that although my answer could resolve your initial question, my answer cannot be used for your additional request.

Comment: @Tanaike Consider undeleting the answer, as the answer answers the question in the post - additional queries need not be answered in the answer.

Comment: @dek Consider accepting the posted answer, if it answered your question.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your comment. I reopened my answer.

Comment: @dek By the way, from `Your script works fine.`, if this question was resolved, please accept the answer. By this, it will be useful for users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I believe your goal is as follows.

- When the value of column "D" is not empty by editing the cell, you want to put the date retrieved by your function `TIMESTAMP` into the same row of column "E".
- You want to fix the cell value.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please set your sheet name, and save the script.

In this modification, the date value from your function `TIMESTAMP` is put into the cell of column "E" using the simple trigger of OnEdit. So, in this case, the cell value of the date is put without the formula. The value is directly put into the cell. By this, the cell value is fixed.

**When you use this script, please edit the cell of column "D". From your formula `=IF(D4<>"";TIMESTAMP();"")`, when the column "D" is not empty, the date is put into the column "E".**

```js
// This is from your showing script.
function TIMESTAMP() {
  var today = new Date();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  var date = today.getDate() + '/' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + today.getFullYear();
  var dateTime = time + '-' + date;
  var timestamp_format = "dd-MM";
  return dateTime;
}

function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.columnStart != 4 || range.rowStart == 1) return;
  range.offset(0, 1).setValue(TIMESTAMP());
}
```

- In this modified script, the value of your function `TIMESTAMP` is used. So, it supposes that the value of your function `TIMESTAMP` is your expected value. Please be careful about this.
- In the above script, when column "D" is edited, the value of `TIMESTAMP()` is put into column "E" as the overwrite even when the column "E" is not empty. If you want to put the value of `TIMESTAMP()` into column "E" when the column "E" is empty, please modify `onEdit` as follows.

  ```js
  function onEdit(e) {
    const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

    const { range } = e;
    const sheet = range.getSheet();
    if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.columnStart != 4 || range.rowStart == 1) return;
    const rightSide = range.offset(0, 1);
    if (rightSide.isBlank()) rightSide.setValue(TIMESTAMP());
  }
  ```

#### Note:

- Please don't directly run `onEdit` function. When you directly run the function `onEdit`, an error like `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'range' of 'e' as it is undefined.` occurs because of no event object. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: The first sheet is named "START" which has a button that runs a script and they press it every day to create a duplicate of the "MASTER" sheet that has all the tasks of the day. 

The duplicated sheet is automatically renamed DD/MM. 

Then they renamed it to the current date (for example today that sheet is renamed 19/10) 30-31 for each month.

That specific sheet is the one that is populated from the answers from column D. So how do I bypass the sheetName that is inside your script to work for each day of the month?

Comment: @dek Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand the issue of my answer. And, I guess that your actual question is different from your showing question. My answer is for your showing question. In this case, I think that my answer was not useful for the actual question in your reply. So, I have to delete my answer. I apologize that I couldn't notice your actual question.