# TIMESTAMP function is updating when I open the Google Sheet to check the file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I use a Google Excel file that I distribute to the store managers of a retail company with branches every month.
The Google Excel file has two locked sheets inside. The first is called “START” and the second “MASTER”.
[START & MASTER sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKGyM.jpg)
On the START sheet it has a button which when pressed creates a copy of the MASTER.
This sheet also, from the script it runs, renames it to DD/MM.
[New Duplicated MASTER renamed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baqub.jpg)
The user, who will use it, renames it to today's date that he created it and will use it.
[Renamed to today's day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH5T5.jpg)
The MASTER file has a series of tasks in column D which through a drop-down list makes the selection (column D). Once he selects then, column E shows the date and time he made the selection.
[Selection Col. D - Time-Date Col.E](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DSHU.jpg)
When I open this file, it is updated to today's time & date, thus altering the real time.

```
[TIMESTAMP SAMPLE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TUYrIkc6C2LYbEPvNzz_oa3rQMsJBJafOMCKu0e2SIg/edit?usp=sharing)
```

The script I run for TIMESTAMP is:

```
// This is from your showing script.
function TIMESTAMP() {
var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var date = today.getDate() + '/' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + today.getFullYear();
var dateTime = time + '-' + date;
var timestamp_format = "dd-MM";
return dateTime;
}
```

Which returns me HH:MM:SS – DD/MM/YYYY.

The script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77323666) that worked more correctly from [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) and I don't even need to add the formula "=IF(D4<>"";TIMESTAMP();"")" inside the cell:

```
// This is from your showing script.
function TIMESTAMP() {
var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var date = today.getDate() + '/' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + today.getFullYear();
var dateTime = time + '-' + date;
var timestamp_format = "dd-MM";
return dateTime;
}

function onEdit(e) {
const sheetName = "Sheet 1test"; // Please set your sheet name.

const { range } = e;
const sheet = range.getSheet();
if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.columnStart != 4 || range.rowStart == 1) return;
range.offset(0, 1).setValue(TIMESTAMP());
}
```

Which has a problem, in order for it to work, I have to set it to the name of the sheet inside the script.

I also tried the below variation in the script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77323495/timestamp-for-function-now-is-updating-when-i-open-the-google-sheet-to-check-t/77323666#comment136324406_77323495) from [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster):
const sheetName=new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB',{day:'2-digit',month:'2-digit'}).format(new Date())

But it only works for one date. If I add another day it doesn't work.

Is there a way to make it work automatically for all days (ie 01-30/31)?

Also, is it possible for the date it shows me to be in DD/MM format only without the year (ie HH:MM:DD - DD/MM) without the year with leading zeros for the time and for the date?

Comment: `. If I add another day it doesn't work.` How did you add another date?

Comment: It looks like you included code from somewhere else. If you're using someone else's work without giving them credit, that constitutes plagiarism, which is not welcome on Stack Exchange. To fix it, [edit] to make sure you do **ALL** the following: 1.Include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, 2. Mention the author's name, and 3. [Quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) the copied content. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your actual expected result, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about giving the exclude sheet names? When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, I guessed that you might not want to run `onEdit` to only the sheets of "START" and "MASTER". If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
// This is from your showing script.
function TIMESTAMP() {
  var today = new Date();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  var date = today.getDate() + '/' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + today.getFullYear();
  var dateTime = time + '-' + date;
  var timestamp_format = "dd-MM";
  return dateTime;
}

function onEdit(e) {
  const excludeSheetNames = ["START", "MASTER"]; // Please set exclude sheet names.

  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (excludeSheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName()) || range.columnStart != 4 || range.rowStart == 1) return;
  range.offset(0, 1).setValue(TIMESTAMP());
}
```

- In this modified script, the script `range.offset(0, 1).setValue(TIMESTAMP());` is run except for the sheets of `excludeSheetNames`.

#### Note:

- By the way, when I saw your provided Spreadsheet, there are 2 `onEdit` functions in your Google Apps Script project. In this case, I'm worried that the script might not be correctly run. So, please remove `onEdit` except for the above sample script. And, test the script.
- And, in your column "E", the formula like `=IF(D3<>"";TIMESTAMP();"")` is still existing. So, for example, when column "D" of "MASTER" is edited, the formula returns a value while `onEdit` is not run. Please be careful about this.

Comment: The formula works fine! Many thanks!! The only thing that remains is how to add the leading zero for hours, minutes, and seconds and the date needs to be only DD/MM without the year. Also, the other onEdit you saw in the App Script is for the checkbox in Column B that returns the start time in Column C which stopped working! How do I fix that?

Comment: @dek Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new 2 questions of `The only thing that remains is how to add the leading zero for hours, minutes, and seconds and the date needs to be only DD/MM without the year.` and `Also, the other onEdit you saw in the App Script is for the checkbox in Column B that returns the start time in Column C which stopped working! How do I fix that?`, I would like to support you. But, I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new 2 questions.

Comment: @dek About 1st question of your new 2 questions, what actual value do you want to retrieve? About the 2nd question of your new 2 questions, I cannot understand what you want to do. I apologize for my poor English skill. In this case, can you post it as a new question? By this, it will help users think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new questions, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Your English is fine probably mine is not. For the 1st question: I want to retrieve the time (hh:mm:ss) and the date 20/10 (DD/MM), not the year. For the 2nd question in the Excel sheet column B, rows 5-7 there is a tick box when ticked, time and date are retrieved in rows 5-7 column C. Check the examples in column F rows 3 & 4

Comment: @dek Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your new 2 questions. But, I would like to support you. So, in this case, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new questions, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77334880/google-sheet-timestamp-script-format-time-with-milliseconds-date-with-day-and