# Google sheet TIMESTAMP script format Time with milliseconds & Date with Day and Month without Year

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

In my Google Sheets, I am using a script [TIMESTAMP for function NOW() is updating when I open the Google Sheet to check the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77323495/timestamp-for-function-now-is-updating-when-i-open-the-google-sheet-to-check-t)
that is been given to me by [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) that retrieves time and date from the selection of a dropdown list in column D to column E.
[capture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbuH8.jpg)

1. I want the format of the time to be with milliseconds and the date without the year.
2. Also, I want if it has a single-digit number (like 8 AM) to have a leading zero in front of the digit.
   [capture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Diq6p.jpg)

Comment: To fix referencing, [edit] to make sure you do **ALL** the following: 1.Include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, 2. Mention the author's name. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).  You forgot to do the first.

Comment: Also, why can't you just manually change the number format?

Comment: @TheMaster I tried it manually but it doesn't work! Also, you commented again to fix the referencing! What did I miss this time? I put the link @Tanaike! What else should I do?

Comment: If you remove `.setNumberFormat()` in Tanaike's code, manual formatting will work.  About referencing, you need to add the actual answer or question link ( check your previous question - I edited in the actual links)

Comment: @Themaster I think that I fixed my post. I am new here. Thank you very much for your guidance, and assistance. I will keep the .setNumberFormat() in mind for the next time. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your showing sample output situation, how about using `Utilities.formatDate` as follows?

#### Modified script 1:

In this case, when you want to put the value as the string value, how about modifying `TIMESTAMP` as follows?

```js
function TIMESTAMP() {
  return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'HH:mm:ss:SSS" - "dd/MM');
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

If you want to put the value as the date object, how about modifying `onEdit` as follows? I think that this might be the same direction as TheMaster's comment. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77334880/google-sheet-timestamp-script-format-time-with-milliseconds-date-with-day-and#comment136336326_77334880)

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const excludeSheetNames = ["START", "MASTER"]; // Please set exclude sheet names.

  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (excludeSheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName()) || range.columnStart != 4 || range.rowStart == 1) return;
  range.offset(0, 1).setNumberFormat('HH:mm:ss:SSS" - "dd/MM').setValue(new Date());

  if (e.value != "TRUE") return;
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart + 1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('HH:MM:SS - dd/MM ');
}
```

- In this modification, `TIMESTAMP` is not used. The number format is changed and the date object is put into the cell.

#### References:

- [formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)
- [setNumberFormat(numberFormat)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat)

Comment: When I put your script in the original file and ran DEBUG I'v got an error: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'range' of 'e' as it is undefined.
onEdit @ TIMESTAMP.gs:9. Do you have any Idea why or do you want me to share a copy of the original Google sheet?

Comment: @dek Thank you for replying. About `When I put your script in the original file and ran DEBUG I'v got an error: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'range' of 'e' as it is undefined. onEdit @ TIMESTAMP.gs:9.`, in this case, I'm worried that you might directly run `onEdit`. If my understanding is correct, such an error occurs because of no event object. In your previous questions, I thought that you had already run the function `onEdit` by the simple trigger. How about this? If I misunderstood your reply, I apologize.

Comment: @dek In your showing script, I think that `onEdit` function is automatically run by editing column "D" of the sheets except for `["START", "MASTER"]`.

Comment: I ran it before but not inside the original file rather in the copy I shared with you with the link. I can make a link to the original copy to test it yourself if that helps! Let me know. Thank you for your assistant!

Comment: @dek Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue from `I ran it before but not inside the original file rather in the copy I shared with you with the link. I can make a link to the original copy to test it yourself if that helps! Let me know. Thank you for your assistant!`. Can I ask you about the details of your current issue?

Comment: Wait please 2 minutes to share the link of a copy of the actual file to check it yourself.

Comment: @dek Isn't your question to obtain the cell value of `08:05:02:150 - 21/10` when `onEdit` is run? I understood like this from your question. If I misunderstood your really expected result, I apologize.

Comment: Here is the link to have look https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jQ37gLtunKd13ExDWdUeFL1IYir_B9QUgHDOgmQeZZY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @dek Thank you for replying and providing your sample Spreadsheet. From your provided Sample Spreadsheet, I confirmed that you are using my 2nd proposed script. Did you want to use my 2nd proposed script? When I tested my proposed 2nd script, no error occurred. When a cell of column "D" is edited, a value is put into column "E". So, I cannot understand your current issue. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. What is your current issue?

Comment: you wrote: "Isn't your question to obtain the cell value of 08:05:02:150 - 21/10 when onEdit is run? I understood like this from your question. If I misunderstood your really expected result, I apologize." it works fine only the error if it means something in the script debugging?

Comment: @dek Thank you for replying. About `it works fine only the error if it means something in the script debugging?`, if you want to run `onEdit` by the debug mode, unfortunately, this cannot be used because of no event object. I apologize for this situation. In your situation, please edit a cel of column "D" except for `excludeSheetNames`. By this, `onEdit` is automatically run with the event object.

Comment: Now with the file I shared with you I ran the debugger works fine. Maybe something like a picture I cave in the cell produced that error. I made a copy paste from the message of the debagger of my original file if that helps: sheet:undefined
excludeSheetNames:Array(2)
0:"START"
1:"MASTER"
sheet:undefined
sheet:undefined

Comment: @dek Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I did accept your solution already! Do you see the checkboxes in column B? There is where I want in column C to add the time when the box is checked to give me the start time. Do you want me to open another question for that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77335642/22766641