# How to make this script work for 2 columns instead of just 1?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I have a Google sheet that has six columns A to F.
It has a script that when you make a selection from the drop-down list in column D puts the time in Column E (Completion Time).
[Google sheet TIMESTAMP script format Time with milliseconds & Date with Day and Month without Year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77334880/google-sheet-timestamp-script-format-time-with-milliseconds-date-with-day-and/77335023?noredirect=1#comment136336864_77335023). The script was written from Mr. [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike).

Ι need to add the start time in column **C** when the checkbox in column **B** is selected.
Checkbox Column B[image]

I tried with the little knowledge I have to change the script from:

```
   if (excludeSheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName()) || range.columnStart != **4** || range.rowStart == 1) return;.
//adding column 2 with a comma to line 11:
if (excludeSheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName()) || range.columnStart != **2, 4** || range.rowStart == 1) return;
```

unfortunately without any success!

Thanks a lot for any help. My programming knowledge is almost zero. I would like to thank Mr. Tanaike again for all his help and patience in helping me.
I must also apologize in advance to the site moderators if my English is not well-written. I am always at your disposal to answer any questions or clarification you need.

I also tried the suggestion with a checkbox and dropdown list:
if (excludeSheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName()) || includes(range.columnStart) [2, 4] || range.rowStart == 1) return;
but it didn't work as well. It has stopped working for both columns **B & D**.
[anwser2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb6ZO.jpg)

Comment: 1. To ping me, comment under my post. I won't get notifications for comments under another post or posts that I haven't previously interacted, even if you use `@TheMaster`. 2. The code you used is completely different from what I wrote. That's not what I wrote at all. Stop making up your own syntax.  3. Did you read the links in the post?

Comment: Hi, To be honest, I tried to but I couldn't really understand. I have to go back to my work now. I will try again tomorrow morning when my mind is more clear. If you could give me the whole syntax it could be easier for me. I am not a programmer, and you cannot teach the 60-year-old man so fast. It's like telling someone to cook Bourguignon by giving salt and pepper. I solved it for the moment with a manual timestamp (Ctrl+Shift+;). Thank you dear for your effort in trying to teach me. I really much appreciated it! I will remember to comment here and not inside the question.

Comment: I gave you the whole syntax. What you put in in is completely different from what I wrote. I expected a copy paste would work. For eg, my syntax starts with `!`. Where is it in your code? My code is `![2, 4].includes(range.columnStart)` Yours is `includes(range.columnStart) [2, 4]` I understand you're 60, but CAN YOU SEE THE DIFFERENCE? Also, have a bit more faith in yourself.. seems to me you're overworked, rather than being old...

Comment: Yes :) it is working at last !!! if (excludeSheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName()) || ![2, 4].includes(range.columnStart) || range.rowStart == 1) return;
Thank you so much for your patience in teaching old dog new tricks!! It is not by accident that you've been called TheMaster!

Comment: Glad to see this worked out. Do me a favor and don't give up on learning new things due to age - it's not over until it is.

Comment: I am working around 18 hours a day. I have 2 hours for myself and 4 hours for sleep. Of course, if I had a little more time I could learn new things but I do not have time for myself for now... I will post one more question that I find difficult that has a solution. But, you never know! Thanks again dear for your help and Mr. Tanaike of course!

Comment: @TheMaster I have a problem with the script TIMESTAMP and I was lucky enough to notice it before I started throwing "knives" at the personnel and it needs to be resolved. When I select any option for some reason the time has always the same result the seconds with the milliseconds are identical. Which is impossible to happen!
15:15:08:008 - 25/10
15:13:37:037 - 25/10
15:13:39:039 - 25/10
15:13:41:041 - 25/10
15:14:37:037 - 25/10
How should address this problem the correct way without making trouble in the forum and to you?

Comment: You asked so many  questions that I don't know what script you're using currently... How about just switching to `onEdit`  script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77335023/)? If you need help, take the time you're free, spend time formulating the question, creating a [mcve] and a "summarizing" title: [ask]. In general, more the time "you" spend writing the question,  the more you value and respect the "volunteers"(our) time.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Just to understand and not make any trouble! I write a new question or edit the old one which actually is your last response to the TIMESTAMP (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77336595/how-to-make-this-script-work-for-2-columns-instead-of-just-1). That has the problem!  After that is the Duplication of the MASTER sheet that Mr. Tanaike replied https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77344055/google-sheet-sheet-duplication

Comment: Better to ask a new one. All your old ones are confusing.  Don't copy paste old question title/body/script into new question. Write entirely from scratch. See [mcve] and [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an another column to the exclusion criteria, use [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

Replace

```
range.columnStart != **2, 4**
```

with

```
![2, 4].includes(range.columnStart)
```

#### To read and practice:

- [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [Not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT)
- [Expressions and Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators)

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 3 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    //e.source.toast("Gate");
    let dt = new Date();
    e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate(),dt.getHours(),dt.getMinutes(),dt.getSeconds(),dt.getMilliseconds()),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"E MM dd HH:mm:ss:S"));
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Have you checked the script that I am using? Where I should add your script? Thank you for your assistance.